# Is it possible to style external svg file with css?

Tags: css, html, svg

Is it possible to style external svg file with css without modifying the svg file content?

`<img src="image/svg/3ds-max.svg">`

And is there any better way to display external svg file in html5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible using an img tag, these are basically similar to bitmaps as far as accessing or modify them is concerned. You could use the `<iframe>` tag with its style attribute instead or alternatively just include the svg inline in the file which you can do with html5.

Comment: Dang :( Anyone have a link to why this is the case?

Comment: @BradleyFlood https://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/

Answer (score 4):

Almost.  If you can embed your SVG directly in your HTML5 document using the `svg` tag, then you can style it with CSS, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #redcircle { stroke:black; stroke-width:5; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle id="redcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="red" /> 
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He asked for external svg, not inline

Comment: True.  But often it's nice knowing the nearest alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed a bit since this question was asked. You can use an SVG injector to make the SVG inline.

With [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) you can add your SVG like this:

```
 <img src="image/svg/3ds-max.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)" >
```

The injector will replace the `<img>` element with the `<svg>` element from the SVG file after is has loaded. Then you can style all elements of the SVG just as any other element in the HTML DOM.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of SVGInject.*

Comment: This answer is a tad misleading, as nothing has changed which allows styling non-inlined SVGs. This solution uses JavaScript on page load to pull in the external SVG and inline the SVG in to the DOM. 9 times out of 10, inlining the SVG in the first place will produce more performant results as you're also saving a bunch of network requests and/or work for the client.

Comment: @DarianMoody But inlining SVGs does not work for dynamic webpages, does not support lazy loading, and makes your source code less readable. We have been using SVG injection successfully for a while and it just works.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said it wouldn't perform as well for the majority. "Inlining SVGs does not work for dynamic webpages", I'm not sure what you mean by this, sorry. Lazy loading - fair point, but the majority of times you'll want to inline an SVG the byte size will be relatively small (think icon sets, logos, etc - you may be doing something where not inlining makes sense). The source code being way less readable is simply not a user-facing problem; also SVG is vastly more readable than a binary image for example.